# How can I find out which site use JavaScript, programmatically?

Tags: javascript

`enter code here`I am trying to conduct an audit on all the sites in the farm as to which use JavaScript.  I assume that parsing for the script HTML tag would be the best way, but I don't know of a proper, efficient way to do this.

[edit] I should have been more specific, but essentially, I need to find all the sites that use JS and also refer to jquery as well.  The problem is that I did a file search for jquery.js and was shocked to find several dozen files and different versions.  The idea is to consolidate it to one file/version if possible.

So, essentially, I need to find both references and log it to a file.

My problem is figuring out the proper command/syntax to parse for the specific lines of code as well as where to put it during the loops to log the URL's.

Here is the crap psuedo PS script I came up with:

```
function RecurseSite() {
    param([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$SiteIdentity) # Calls SharePoint PowerShell command to identify site(s)

    Write-Output "Site: $($SiteIdentity.Url)" # Grabs site URL

    if($SiteIdentity.Webs.Count -gt 0)  # Cursed Recursion
    {
        foreach($subWeb in $SiteIdentity.Webs)
        {
            RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $subWeb
        }
    }
}

    $contentWebAppServices = (Get-SPFarm).services |
     ? {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}

    foreach($webApp in $contentWebAppServices.WebApplications)
    {
        Write-Output "Web Application: $($webApp.name)"
        Out-File -filepath output.txt
        foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
        {
            Write-Output "Site Collection: $($siteColl.Url)"
            Out-File -filepath output.txt
            RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $($siteColl.RootWeb)
        }
    }
```

Comment: all sites will use javascript, unless you mean custom javascript...?

Comment: To support @Mike comment, even SharePoint it self uses many javascript code and that has even increased with 2013 version of SharePoint.

Comment: This will be for custom JavaScript calls - mostly to jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a some security audits ;) Nearly all sites in SharePoint use JavaScript. I think for an audit it would be more interesting to look for custom JavaScript.

For that i would traverse through all sites and search for .js files that are not in the hive folder:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

To search for inline JavaScript i would write a powershell script that opens up all my sites and search for inline  tags.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function Get-WebPage($url)
{
    [net.httpWebRequest] $request = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
    $request.Timeout = 600000
    $request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    #$req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential($username, $pwd, $domain); 
    [net.httpWebResponse] $response = $request.getResponse()
    $responseStream = $response.getResponseStream()
    $sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($responseStream)
    $result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
    return $result
}  

$URLs =
@("https://www.yourFirstSite.com",
  "https://www.yourSecondSite.com",
  )

$URLs | ForEach-Object {
    try{
        $content = Get-WebPage($_);
        //do your <script> tag search here
        //...
    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "An error occured: "
        Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
    }
}
```

But trust me there is much more you need to consider on an audit... Especially if you have many custom solutions deployed.

Comment: I like your approach.  I was tryign to recursively find all the sites and then doing the <script> tag search and if it came back TRUE, then it would log it to a file.

Comment: Then vote me up :D

Comment: It won't let me upvote... not enough reputation points... so lame

Comment: Now it should work. You have 15 points.

Comment: Yup!  I smashed that up arrow like it owes me money!

Comment: Hahaha great :D